# MVC Frameworks for Windows Mobile Native Code

Tags: c++, model-view-controller, windows-mobile

Are there any good MVC frameworks for native Windows Mobile code?

Barring that could someone link to an open source Windows Mobile or CE project that uses the MVC pattern?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could try Qt. It provides some classes for mvc programming. Here is link for MVC in Qt. http://doc.trolltech.com/4.4/model-view-programming.html

Comment: I believe Model-View programming is similar with Document/View in MFC, not really MVC

Answer (score 1):

Inspired by akam129, this is a [link](http://doc.trolltech.com/qq/qq10-mvc.html) from Qt Quarterly on MVC.

Overview: The controls in Qt are using MVC internally, and it is possible to do MVC programming at application level by using signal-slot mechanism